# Avro union field with "local-timestamp-millis" deserialization issue

Tags: apache-beam, avro, dataflow

- Avro: 10.1
- Dataflow (Apache Beam): 2.28.0
- Runner: org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner

Avro schema piece:

```
{
  "name": "client_timestamp",
  "type": [
    "null",
    { "type": "long", "logicalType": "local-timestamp-millis" }
  ],
  "default": null,
  "doc": "Client side timestamp of this xxx"
},
```

An exception when writing Avro output file:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: 
Not in union ["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"local-timestamp-millis"}]: 
2021-03-12T12:21:17.599
```

[Link to a longer stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/rulle-io/e833d8a9515508ee3ed35bd2df7ed840)

Some of the steps taken:

- Replacing `"logicalType":"local-timestamp-millis"` with `"logicalType":"timestamp-millis"` causes the same error.
- Writing Avro locally also works.
- Removing `"type": "null"` option eliminates the exception

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following:

```
{
    "name": "client_timestamp",
    "type": ["null", "long"],
    "doc": "Client side timestamp of this xxx",
    "default": null,
    "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
}
```

It is a way to define `logicalType` in avro schema ([link](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Logical+Types)).

Comment: The drawback of this approach will be that `client_timestamp` will have type `java.lang.Long`, which defeats the purpose of logicalType `timestamp-millis`.